# Custom UITableViewCells's UITextField mixing up after scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

I created a custom `UITableViewCell` with a `UITextField`, `UILabels` and `UIButtons`. When I enter a value to a `UITextField` and scroll down, it disappears and shows in another random cell. The same problem happens with my `UIButton`, when I press it, the state is changing but after I scroll down, it disappears.

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"produktCell";
    //NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"produktCell %d",indexPath.row];

    ProduktTableViewCell *cell =(ProduktTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
          NSLog(@"wird neu erstellt");
        cell = [[ProduktTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }



    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.produktnameLabel.text = [managedObject valueForKey:@"produktname"]; 



    if ([[managedObject valueForKey:@"vondatum"] length] > 1){
        cell.vonDatumLabel.text = [managedObject valueForKey:@"vondatum"];
        cell.bisDatumLabel.text = [managedObject valueForKey:@"bisdatum"]; 

    }else {
        cell.vonDatumLabel.text = dateString;
        cell.bisDatumLabel.text = dateString1;
    }  


        cell.datumButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.warenkorbButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.menge.tag = indexPath.row + 437812;
    cell.mengeLabel.text = [managedObject valueForKey:@"mengelabel"];
    cell.produktnameLabel.tag = indexPath.row +22333;
    cell.mengeLabel.tag =indexPath.row;


    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *german = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"de_DE"];
    [formatter setLocale:german];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];


    NSNumber *firstNumber = [managedObject valueForKey:@"preis"];

    cell.preisLabel.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:firstNumber];



    return cell;
}
```

EDIT: i fixed my problem with the textfield. i just delete the method:

```
   /*- (void) scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{


   [[self.tableView superview] endEditing:YES];


}*/
```

but there is still a problem with my button.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess, is that your cells that are being re-used, are receiving the same behavior of the cell that you just interacted with. You can try something quick to see what I mean. Comment this:

Edit:

```
   ProduktTableViewCell *cell =(ProduktTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
          NSLog(@"wird neu erstellt");
        cell = [[ProduktTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

Put this instead:

```
ProduktTableViewCell *cell = [[ProduktTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

This way your new cells won't get the same "state" as the previous cell. What you need to do next, is to know which cell are you working on. Besides that you still need to reset the state of new cells. **To finish, uncomment what I told you to comment (since you want your cells to be re-usable)**

Comment: when i comment this line it have the same behavior. the tableview still mixes up.

Comment: i tried it, but i can't get into (cell==nil). the tableview is empty and the NSLog isn't called.

Comment: sorry but the tableview is still empty :S

Comment: Let's do the following, contact me by using my email. I will try to help by other means.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11003/discussion-between-eray-geveci-and-jacky-boy)